# How to deploy a GAE project in flexible environment without billing?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I've been developing some REST service using Flask and other third party libraries and I want to deploy it to GAE in the flexible environment. I usually deploy to the GAE standard environment but I wanted to try the new flexible environment. At the moment I wish to deploy to flexible environment without enabling billing, and the Google support assured me that it was possible to deploy over GAE flexible environment without enabling billing.

Running my code locally works fine, and have the following yaml file:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT whereismybus230.starter:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

So I created a new project on through the Google cloud console web page (as usual), and created a new gcloud profile on my local machine so I deploy it to this new project.
Then I run:

```
gcloud app deploy --verbosity=info
```

I get that a docker image is being build and at some point it will be pushed to a Compute Engine but it fails after a few minutes here:

```
Successfully built sophiabus230 aniso8601 future docopt itsdangerous MarkupSafe
Installing collected packages: Werkzeug, click, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, Flask, jsonschema, pytz, six, python-dateutil, aniso8601, flask-restplus, beautifulsoup4, future, sophiabus230, coverage, requests, docopt, coveralls
Successfully installed Flask-0.12 Jinja2-2.9.4 MarkupSafe-0.23 Werkzeug-0.11.15 aniso8601-1.2.0 beautifulsoup4-4.5.3 click-6.7 coverage-4.3.4 coveralls-1.1 docopt-0.6.2 flask-restplus-0.9.2 future-0.16.0 itsdangerous-0.24 jsonschema-2.5.1 python-dateutil-2.6.0 pytz-2016.10 requests-2.12.5 six-1.10.0 sophiabus230-0.4
 ---> 3e3438680079
Removing intermediate container bd9f8ccb6f4a
Step 8 : ADD . /app/
 ---> bde0915f6720
Removing intermediate container e3193eb4ef70
Step 9 : CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT whereismybus230.starter:app
 ---> Running in 022d38d769f8
 ---> 36893d0a549a
Removing intermediate container 022d38d769f8
Successfully built 36893d0a549a
PUSH
The push refers to a repository [us.gcr.io/whereismy230/appengine/default.20170120t131841]
e5f488ee94c5: Preparing
8d27ce27f03c: Preparing
3d5800d45c36: Preparing
06ba8a2a8ec3: Preparing
c0fb81dae3c6: Preparing
2e4eabdbeed3: Preparing
b5d474284f52: Preparing
c307273999be: Preparing
d73750730c30: Preparing
63bbaf04cf0b: Preparing
badb9b2d625b: Preparing
40c928fd4dcc: Preparing
dfcf8dbe47e1: Preparing
6d820e13990c: Preparing
2e4eabdbeed3: Waiting
b5d474284f52: Waiting
c307273999be: Waiting
d73750730c30: Waiting
63bbaf04cf0b: Waiting
badb9b2d625b: Waiting
40c928fd4dcc: Waiting
dfcf8dbe47e1: Waiting
6d820e13990c: Waiting
denied: Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.
The push refers to a repository [us.gcr.io/whereismy230/appengine/default.20170120t131841]
...
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [2] Build failed; check build logs for details
```

Using the IAM service, I made sure my account was the owner of the project, and even checked all permissions.
Since the flexible environment relies on the Compute Engines (VMs), I tried to check from the web page and it's telling me that I need to enable billing to be able to use this functionality.

Am I doing something wrong ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From  [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing):

> Instances within the standard environment have access to a daily
>   limit of resource usage that is provided at no charge defined by a set
>   of [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas). Beyond that level, applications will incur charges as
>   outlined below. To control your application costs, you can set a
>   [spending limit](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#spending_limit). To estimate costs for the standard environment,
>   use the pricing calculator.
>
> [Go to the pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/#tab=app-engine)
>
> For instances within the flexible environment, services and APIs are
>   priced as described below.

And from [Flexible environment instances](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-instances):

> Applications running in the App Engine flexible environment are
>   deployed to virtual machine types that you specify. This table
>   summarizes the hourly billing rates of the various computing
>   resources:
>
> ```
> US
> Resource  Unit    Unit cost
> vCPU  per core hour   $0.0526
> Memory    per GB hour     $0.0071
> Persistent disk   per GB per month    $0.0400
> ```

Unlike the standard env, the flex env has no free quota. Which is inline with your observation that the developer console requires billing to be enabled to run GAE flex instances.

Without billing enabled you *might* be able to deploy your app (but without actually launching a GAE instance for it, so unsure of its usefulness, since you want to try it) by using the `--no-promote` option:

> `--promote`
>
> Promote the deployed version to receive all traffic.
>
> True by default. To change the default behavior for your current
>   environment, run:
>
> ```
>   $ gcloud config set app/promote_by_default false
> ```
>
> Overrides the default `promote_by_default` property value for this
>   command invocation. Use `--no-promote` to disable.

Side note: when you encounter problems you may also want to use `--verbosity=debug` to potentially get more relevant info about the failures.

Comment: This info is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for the links ! This has also been confirmed by the Google support. I ended up using Heroku for that matter.